# Is the Static IP in Lightsail same as Elastic IP?

Tags: amazon-elastic-ip, amazon-lightsail

What is the difference between Static IP in Lightsail, and an Elastic IP if any?

I am trying to request a reverse DNS entry with AWS for my mail server. I did not have a Lightsail Static IP and the support team said I need an Elastic IP. So I added a Lightsail Static IP. I am hoping it is same as an Elastic IP. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of LightSail, I believe it is - You can unassign and re-assign this IP as needed to different instances, the same as a Elastic IP for EC2s. If you didn't have one, you would get a new one each time you rebooted - So a RDNS for it wouldn't really be worthwhile.

Reference: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-static-ip-addresses-in-amazon-lightsail

Comment: Confirmation: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-configuring-reverse-dns

Comment: It is probably Elastic IP "under the hood," but there is an important difference: they don't provide an option to migrate the IP from lightsail to EC2. Which is strange because that would help people scale up and spend more emoney.